# Go言語におけるインターフェースと構造体のフィールドへのアクセスについて

Tags: go

Go言語でinterfaceと構造体を以下のように定義しました。

```
type Human interface {
    Greeting()
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p Person) Greeting() {
    fmt.Println("Hello" + p.Name)
}

func main() {
    var John Human = Person{Name: "John"}
    John.Greeting()
}
```

このようにした場合、main関数内からPerson構造体のフィールドであるNameにアクセスする方法はあるのでしょうか。
`John.Name`としてもエラーが発生し値を取得することができませんでした。インターフェースを

```
type Human interface {
    Greeting()
    getName() string
}
func (p Person) getName() string {
    return p.Name
}
```

などとして、`John.getName()`とするしかないのでしょうか。

Comment: 変数 `John` を interface の `Human` 型ではなくて `Person` 型で作成すれば良いのではないでしょうか。`John := Person{Name: "John"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var john Human = Person{Name: "John"}` として定義したとして、`Human` 型 には `Name` フィールドが無いので、おっしゃるとおり `john.Name` では取得できません。

`Name` を無理矢理取得するには、たとえば[型アサーション](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)を使うことで、interface の実装となっている `Person` 型として扱う方法が考えられます：`john.(Person).Name`（[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ckmFwBbja5Y)）。

ただし、もし初めから `Name` へのアクセスが必須だと分かっているのであれば、`john` を `Person` 型として定義した上で `Human` interface の機能も使う、という風にした方が自然でしょう。

```
var john Person = Person{Name: "John"}
john.Greeting()
fmt.Println("Hi, " + john.Name)
```

（[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dNknOoQ2wCp)）

Comment: 型アサーションを用いる方法で取得できるとのこと、ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、最初からPerson型で定義するほうが良いのかもしれません。